# How can I set the font-family & font-size inside of a div?

Tags: html, css, font-size, font-family

This is my complete test html:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>DIV Font</title>

        <style>
            .my_text
            {
                font-family:    Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
                font-size:      40px;
                font-weight:    bold;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="my_text">some text</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The font-family & font-size attributes are being ignored.

[image: page result]

Why? Why is font-weight used? What do I need to do so I can specify the font-family & font-size?

Thank you

Comment: it is because you forgot to put semicolon after font-family:    Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need a semicolon after `font-family:    Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif`. This will make your updated code the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>DIV Font</title>

        <style>
            .my_text
            {
                font-family:    Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-size:      40px;
                font-weight:    bold;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="my_text">some text</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Append a semicolon to the following line to fix the issue.

```
font-family:    Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
```